# Push android com SNS Amazon

Tags: android, push-notification

Estou tentando fazer o push de um aplicativo android, mas não estou conseguindo receber o push em meu app.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.REGISTER" />
<uses-permission android:name="br.com.bencao.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<permission
    android:name="br.com.bencao.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<application
    android:name=".core.RootApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- [START gcm_receiver] -->
    <receiver
        android:name=".gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="br.com.bencao" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- [END gcm_receiver] -->

    <!-- [START gcm_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="br.com.bencao.gcm.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END gcm_listener] -->

    <!-- [START instanceId_listener] -->
    <service
        android:name="br.com.bencao.gcm.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!-- [END instanceId_listener] -->

    <service
        android:name="br.com.bencao.gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.BencaoDiaActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_bencao_dia"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SobreActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sobre"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.DicasActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dicas"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.DicaExibirActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dica_exibir"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MensagensActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mensagens"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MensagensExibirActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mensagens_exibir"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

QuickstartPreferences.java

```
package br.com.bencao.gcm;

public class QuickstartPreferences {

    public static final String SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER = "SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER";
    public static final String REGISTRATION_COMPLETE = "REGISTRATION_COMPLETE";

}
```

MyGcmListenerService .java

```
package br.com.bencao.gcm;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

import br.com.bencao.R;
import br.com.bencao.activity.MainActivity;

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param from SenderID of the sender.
     * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
     *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        /**
         * Production applications would usually process the message here.
         * Eg: - Syncing with server.
         *     - Store message in local database.
         *     - Update UI.
         */

        /**
         * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to the user
         * that a message was received.
         */
        sendNotification(message);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
     *
     * @param message GCM message received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

MyInstanceIDListenerService.java

```
package br.com.bencao.gcm;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService;

public class MyInstanceIDListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyInstanceIDLS";

    /**
     * Called if InstanceID token is updated. This may occur if the security of
     * the previous token had been compromised. This call is initiated by the
     * InstanceID provider.
     */
     // [START refresh_token]
     @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Fetch updated Instance ID token and notify our app's server of any changes (if applicable).
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
}
```

GcmBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package br.com.bencao.gcm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                MyGcmListenerService.class.getName());
        Log.i("gcm", "receive");
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

RegistrationIntentService.java

```
package br.com.bencao.gcm;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmPubSub;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID;

import java.io.IOException;

import br.com.bencao.R;

public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

    public RegistrationIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        try {
            // [START register_for_gcm]
            // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
            // are local.
            // [START get_token]
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
            // [END get_token]
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

            // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
            sendRegistrationToServer(token);

            // Subscribe to topic channels
            subscribeTopics(token);

            // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
            // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
            // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
            // [END register_for_gcm]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
            // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
            // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
        }
        // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
        Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
    }

    /**
     * Persist registration to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
     *
     * @param token GCM token
     * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
     */
    // [START subscribe_topics]
    private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
        for (String topic : TOPICS) {
            pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
        }
    }
    // [END subscribe_topics]

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package br.com.bencao.activity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;

import br.com.bencao.R;
import br.com.bencao.animacoes.FadeInOut;
import br.com.bencao.core.RootActivity;
import br.com.bencao.core.RootApplication;
import br.com.bencao.gcm.QuickstartPreferences;
import br.com.bencao.gcm.RegistrationIntentService;
import br.com.bencao.ws.BencaoDados;


public class MainActivity extends RootActivity {

    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    RootApplication rootApplication;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rootApplication = (RootApplication)getApplicationContext();

        Typeface tfb = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf");
        TextView carregando_txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.carregando_dados);
        carregando_txt.setTypeface(tfb);

        FadeInOut anim = new FadeInOut();
        anim.setAnim(carregando_txt);

        new BencaoDados(MainActivity.this).execute();

        Log.e("token", rootApplication.getAndroid_token());

        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                boolean sentToken = sharedPreferences
                        .getBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false);
                if (sentToken) {
                    Log.e("gcm", "a");
                } else {
                    Log.e("gcm", "b");
                }
            }
        };

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // Start IntentService to register this application with GCM.
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
                apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Estou usando SNS para enviar o push, alguém consegue identificar algum erro ou algo faltando no código?

Comment: Retorna algum erro no Logcat?

Comment: Não, funciona normal, porém quando disparo o push do SNS não recebe

Comment: siga o passo a passo... mais algo na sua parte web deve estar errado.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-gcm.html https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/aws/push-notifications-to-mobile-devices-using-amazon-sns/

Comment: Coloque um breakpoint em `String message = data.getString("message");` provavelmente esta vindo outra coisa além de **message** no seu data. Aconteceu comigo.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a documentação do Amazon SNS e do GCM para android,  você precisa completar 3 requisitos básicos:

- **O aplicativo precisa estar registrado junto ao GCM**: você deve ter um aplicativo com a API do Google Cloud Messaging habilitada no Google Developers Console.
- **Possuir uma chave de autenticação da API GCM** (sender auth token), este token é utilizado no cabeçalho da mensagem direcionada ao GCM. Se incorreto ou ausente, o servidor do Google retorna um erro de autenticação e não envia a mensagem. O mesmo é obtido ao registrar o aplicativo no Google Developers Console.
- Você precisa ter um **Registration ID**. Ele é necessário para o envio das mensagens, pois é o identificador único de cada instância do seu aplicativo.
  A classe responsável por obtê-lo é a `RegistrationIntentService`, que utiliza o método `instanceID.getToken()`. Observe que você não implementou o método `sendRegistrationToServer`, que é responsável por registrar o token gerado pelo Google Play Services no seu servidor. Sem ele, não é possível direcionar as mensagens para um dispositivo específico.

Criei uma aplicação de exemplo com estas funcionalidades. O código fonte e um pequeno tutorial estão disponíveis no Github: [Cliente Android](https://github.com/MathiasBerwig/Push) e [Servidor PHP](https://github.com/MathiasBerwig/Push-server).

*Infelizmente não pude complementar a resposta com links para a documentação devido às restrições de reputação do StackOverflow.*